# Is it possible deleting files from a different URL?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how I could delete a file from a different URL.

The situation is similar to the one below.

Eg: **abc.com/admin/xyz-admin** updates the content of **xyz.com**.

The website **XYZ** has the folders with images, so I want to delete files from there with **abc.com/admin/xyz-admin**. I'm using Remote MySQL to connect the database.

Thanks!

Comment: An API on xyz.com to list folders/images and delete them.

Comment: There're many ways to trigger a remote file deletion through a public network but of course they all require a properly set up tool set, not something you can routinely do without the target server intervention (so, nope, you can't delete Google). Said that, I'm afraid this question is way too vague to be properly answered.

Comment: I have access to both. I'm learning some PHP functions, and it isn't about deleting Google. I'm looking for recommendations as Craigmj wrote below. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You need to use FTP (or SFTP) or some protocol like that to log on to xyz.com and delete the files 'manually'.

See the [PHP documentation on FTP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php).

Note that you would need an FTP server installed on xyz.com, and FTP is not a secure protocol.

You could also use WebDAV, for which there are some PHP libraries like https://sabre.io/dav/davclient/. Again, you would need a WebDAV server on xyz.com